# Using CSS filter on iframe in slick.js carousel applies filter to images, but not background

Tags: html, css, iframe, slick.js, css-filters

So I have a page where I am loading a number of pages as iframes in a carousel (using slick.js). I had applied a brightness(70%) css filter to the div that contains the iframe that is not the current active item, and once the user clicks onto it, it's brightness will change to a 100%, with the previously selected one becoming 70%.. and so on.

Now this was working great until a couple of weeks back or so, when I noticed that the filters were flickering? But that was actually caused by the filter only being applied to the images and text but not the actual iframe body, which became transparent after the filter is applied.

Here is the edited slick css chunk  ( siteloader is the div that contains the iframe)

```
.slick-slide .siteloader{
 margin-top:60px;
 width: 180px;
 height: 338px;
 filter: brightness(70%);
 transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.slick-center .siteloader{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 240px;
 height: 450px;
 filter: brightness(100%);
 transition: all 300ms ease;
 border-color: #a4a4a4;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

*Added updated html and razor code sample and updated images*

this is the code for how the carousel is generated. The pages are loaded dynamically

```
        <div class="template-carousel">
            <h3 style="margin:0">Choose a template</h3>
            <div class="center">
                @{
                    var m = 0;
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.TemplateList)
                    {
                        var itemClass = m++ > ViewBag.TemplateList.Count ? "slick-current" : "";
                <div class="@itemClass" id="@item.Id" data-tempid="@item.Id">
                    <div class="siteloader">
                        <object data="@item.PageURL" style="height:100%;width:100%"></object>
                    </div>

                    <h4>@item.Name</h4>

                </div>

                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

[what I get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p15qw.jpg) vs [what I used to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6P54.jpg)

See images of what I want vs what I am getting.
Could this be an issue caused by changes to Chrome or some CSS spec change?

Comment: is it possible for you to give more code or a working demo? I do not believe this will get effected by any new changes. Also, you can try replacing `.slick-center` by `.slick-active`. Slick center works only when you have the centre mode as true, but slick-active works in all situations.

Comment: Is the image the only thing being iframed or is it the entire slide? That screen shot is kind of miraculous, I would have guessed applying a CSS filter to an iframe would do nothing. You don't have to support IE, do you?

Comment: The entire slide is an iframe. As in each individual slide is a webpage. It did work fine before, so Im not sure what has change. Will edit my question to include more code

Comment: well I guess its not an iframe loading a page and more an object loading a page too.